# action mode not working in ExpandableListView in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-actionmode

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.asite.adoddle.R;
import com.asite.adoddle.adapter.ExpandableAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    ExpandableAdapter listAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    //ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        /*listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,new String[]{"A","B","C","D"}));
        listView.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);*/
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expListView.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        expListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
                Toast.makeText(ExpandableActivity.this, i + " selected = "+b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.addtoofflinemenu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }

}
```

Here is My code to enable action mode in **ExpandableListView**. When I long click on any item, then action mode becomes enable, but when I select any item , ***onItemCheckedStateChanged*** method doesn't call.

Answer (score 1):

To make onItemCheckedStateChanged called, you need to implement setOnChildClickListener and implement its onChildClick(). Then call setItemChecked() method from there. 
Example:

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long l) {
            int index = expandableListView.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
            if(isActionModeEnabled){
                expListView.setItemChecked(index,true);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.